# Why is there a Blank Preview on Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

The application was working just fine. i was exploring the Android Studio and I don"t know what went wrong. The image shows the current situation I am in. Please help me find it's Solution.
The Shown Error>>  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ4hk.jpg

Comment: See the red exclamation mark in the top right? Click that. If you can't figure it out, post the error that shows.

Comment: Open Link [1] for the screenshot of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the buttons for "Refresh Layout" and "Clear Cache". Also clean and rebuild and restart android studio. Make sure you have the correct version of the libraries you need in your dependencies as well.